# VBA to trigger multiple workbook events independently

Tags: excel, vba, triggers

I want to trigger code within a sheet but instead of a single cell value triggering an event(which I have found lots of examples of), I want to one cell to trigger one event and another cell to trigger off another independent.  Would appreciate any help out there?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: If you're talking about using the Worksheet_Change event to do different tasks when different cells are changed?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  I am talking about using the Worksheet_Change event to do different tasks when different cells are changed.  So, I want to tigger an event based on Cell A1 and also trigger an event based on Cell A2.  the events are unrelated and I was struggling on how to condition the code to examine both Cells to trigger different events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly Scott, you could achieve what you appear to be after with a single Private Sub containing multiple If conditions.  The following sub will run different code whether the values in cell A1 or B1 changes.  Simple insert the desired code where indicated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then

     'Some code here runs if the value in cell A1 changes

    End If

    If Not Intersect(Range("B1"), Target) Is Nothing Then

     'Different code here runs if the value in cell B1 changes

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I like having a single Private Sub, thanks.  Where Im still unclear is where in this code do I define the value in cell A1 or B1 to trigger the desired code to run? For example, I want some code to run if the value in cell A1 = "Name" and I want to run different code if the value in cell B1 = "Address". Thanks in advance

Comment: The sub I suggested will cause code to run simply if there’s a change of any sort in cells A1 or B1.  If you want specific code to run based on exact changes to these cells, you could add an AND condition to the end of the “If Not Intersect” line as such:

If Not Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing And _ Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "Name" Then

Comment: works perfectly fine - thanks much

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case (Target.Address)
        Case "$A$1":
            Call EventNr1
        Case "$A$2":
            Call EventNr2
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub EventNr1()
    MsgBox "Hello 1"
End Sub

Private Sub EventNr2()
    MsgBox "Hello 2"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sure this question will show my inexperience: where do I inform the code what content/value in Cell A1 triggers EventNr1 or in Cell A2 triggers EventNr2?